# Trouble running passport login Strategy. Authentication error~ TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

#### Things I've tried

> - Moving the authenticate directly into the server
> - Uninstalling and reinstalling the following(**as well as their corresponding types**):
>
>   - *passport*
>   - *passport-jwt*
>   - *passport-local*

**All of these still result in getting the following error message**: 
 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined"~Crashing the app

#### Code

##### Server File

```js
import * as express from "express";
import apiRouter from "./routes/index";
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as PassportLocal from 'passport-local';


import './middleware/passport-stradegies';

const app = express();


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(apiRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${port}`));
```

##### Passport Login Code

```js
import * as passport from 'passport';
import * as PassportLocal from 'passport-local';
import blogs from "../db/blogs";
import { compareHash } from "../utils";

passport.serializeUser((user, done)=> done(null, user));
passport.deserializeUser((user, done)=> done(null, user));

passport.use(new PassportLocal.Strategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
},async (email, password, done) =>{
    try {
         const [userFound] = await blogs.find("email", email);
          if (userFound && compareHash(password, userFound.userpassword)) {
            done(null, userFound);
    }else{
        done(null, false);
    }
    } catch (error) {
        done(error);
    }
}))
```

##### Login / Token Creation Page

```js
import * as express from "express";
// import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { authenticate } from 'passport';
import config from '../../config';


const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", authenticate('local'), async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
  //     const token = jwt.sign({
  //       userid: userFound.id, email: userFound.email, role: 1}, 
  //       config.jwt.secret, {expiresIn: '15d'}
  //       );
  //     return res.json(token);
    res.json('plz');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "My code login broke oops" });
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Try to debug what `passport` actually is. Looks like it's `undefined` instead of imported module. Make sure you didn't overwrite variable elsewhere.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob could you explain what you mean by that? Do you mean console.log(passport)?

Comment: `console` is not the best way to debug )) But ok for this time, try to output `passwort` value.

Comment: Well, this is interesting when I commented out the problem code. I still get the same error? Authenticate is now commented out so this seems really weird.

Comment: Check error's stack trace, your error comming from elsewhere

Comment: I was able to console log passport it seems normal, but it's too big to comment here. When I trace the error it says that it is coming from the login page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239286/discussion-between-wayne-and-xeelley).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The only problem is passport changed how authenticate is imported

#### In login/token Authentication Page

##### Change the import:

```js
// import { authenticate } from 'passport'; to
import * as passport from 'passport';

// then anywhere you use authenticate just use passport.authenticate
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are calling authenticate(). When the function is called independently, without being bound to the passport object, you get the 'cannot read properties of undefined' error. For example, this will cause an error:

```
import passport from 'passport'
const authenticate = passport.authenticate
//...
authenticate('bearer')(req, res, next)
```

But this will not cause an error:

```
import passport from 'passport'
//...
passport.authenticate('bearer')(req, res, next)
```

This too is okay:

```
import passport from 'passport'
const authenticate = passport.authenticate.bind(passport)
//...
authenticate('bearer')(req, res, next)
```